# How can I redirect my Home Page in Magento? (301 permanent redirect)

Tags: magento-1, redirect

I have a CMS-Website and a SHOP-Wensite and I try to redirect the Magento Homepage to my CMS-Homepage. At my server the cms and magento are in two diffrent folders. If I click at myshop.domain.com it should be redirect to cms.domain.com

I've tried with a new page in magento and at "system > configuration > web > default pages" I choose my new page as home page.

At this page I can't use PHP (header location) ...or Javascript (document.location.href)

How can I redirect (301) my Magento HomePage to my CMS-Homepage?

With htaccess?
I found Catalog > URL Redirects  but my 301 didn't work?!

Answer (score 6):

You should set `../` as target path, see the screenshot below:

[image]

Now request to `www.domain.com/network-nvr201-08lp` will redirect to `www.domain.com`.

Comment: @konstatin: Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Catalog > URL Rewrite Management > Add New URL Rewrite

Refer

- http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-tutorials/301-redirects-in-magento/
- http://blog.maximusbusiness.com/2012/10/magento-url-rewriting-regex-and-301-redirects-tips/

Comment: It worked if I try http://myshop.domain.com/test.html  redirect 301 to http://google.com or what ever, but if I try "/" redirect to "http://cms.domain.com .. nothing happend

Comment: Thanks for your tips, but I want to redirect my HomePage (/) and that doesen't work. I work with 1.13.0

Comment: I found this, but It doesn't work

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L][]

Answer (score 1):

I know this comes a couple of years later, but I've found myself in that same problem today.

I've solved it with a RewriteRule on the .htaccess file. In my case it's been something similar to:

```
GOOD EXAMPLE:
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) https://myothersite.com/myimages [L,R=301]
```

It worked like a charm!

I've found that it is important the order of the optional flags. For example:

```
BAD EXAMPLE - DO NOT USE!
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) https://myothersite.com/myimages **[R=301,L]**
```

Didn't work and was giving me a 500 HTTP error code.

Adding to the links shown on Srikanth AD answer I'm adding this one too (disclaimer 2: this is autopromo as I've written it myself :P):

- http://www.easydevmixin.com/2015/10/14/easy-magento-redirects/

Coming late, but hope it helps someone else!